# MySQL выбрать записи за прошлый день?

Tags: mysql, sql

Собственно вопрос, как выбрать все записи за прошлый день? Такая конструкция работает (datatime):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= (CURDATE()-1) AND date < CURDATE()
```

Но если например день 01.08.16, то записи не выбираются. Как лучше изменить запрос?

Comment: используйте datediff() http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Comment: WHERE date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY )

Answer (score 2):

CURDATE возвращает текстовое значение вида "2016-08-01", конструкция CURDATE()-1 приведет к тому, что значение будет приведено к числовому виду и будет выведено 20160800.

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND CURDATE();
```

Данный запрос выведет все записи за предыдущий день с 00:00 до 23:59.